# Does the term 'closure of a sequence' exist?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Can the closure of a sequence be defined? And if this is possible, how? Suppose there is a convergent sequence $(x_k)_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ in $\mathbb{R}^m$, so $\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}x_k=x\in\mathbb{R}^m$. Is the closure of $(x_k)_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ equal to $\{x\}$, or $\{x\}\cup \{x_k|k\in\mathbb{N}\}$, or something else?

Comment: A sequence defines a set: $\{x_n : \forall n \in \mathbb{N}, x_n \text{ satisfies a property} \}$ the closure of this is the set itself and all of its limit points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't recall having ever seen that expression, but I think that it is natural to call closure of the sequence $(x_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ to the set $\overline{\{x_n\mid n\in\Bbb N\}}$. With this definition, if $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=x$, then the closure of $(x_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ is $\{x_n\mid n\in\Bbb N\}\cup\{x\}$. More generally, the closure of $(x_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ is the union of the set $\{x_n\mid n\in\Bbb N\}$ with the set of all limits of all convergent subsequences of $(x_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$.